# Import sibling module in Python

Tags: python, import, module, package

I want to import sibling module.

I searched for it and got dozens of solutions. But it all didn't work at all.

This is the example structure.

```
test/
  + __init__.py
  + A.py

  + test_B/
    + __init__.py
    + B.py

  + test_C/
    + __init__.py
    + C.py
```

I tried to import module B in module C.

```py
# import test_B.B 
# => Error!

# import test.test_B.B 
# => Error!

# from test.test_B import B
# => Error!

# from ..test_B import B
# => Error!

# from test_B import B
# => Error!

# import sys
# sys.path.insert(0, "../test_B")
# import B
# import test_B.B
# => Error!
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a method.

```py
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
from test_B import B
```

This method works good.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.